# Godot 4: Via code generate array of radio buttons and link them to a custom signal

Tags: radio-button, godot

Attempting to have a radio button press action result in the button's number being printed to the console. Current code only prints "Button #_of_highest_button was pressed" regardless of which button was actually pressed. The problem has to be with the way I'm setting up the signal, but I can't figure it out.

```
signal button_pressed

func create_radio_button_matrix():
    var row_count = len(Global.players) - 1
    var index = Global.players.find(Global.active_player)
    var players = Global.players.duplicate()
    players.pop_at(index)
    for player in players:
        for row in row_count:
            group = ButtonGroup.new()
            for col in 4:
                button = Button.new()
                gray_foreground.add_child(button)
                button.set_button_group(group)
                button.position = Vector2(200 + 100 * col, 150 + 35 * row)
                button.size = Vector2(95, 20)
                button.toggle_mode = true
                button.action_mode = BaseButton.ACTION_MODE_BUTTON_PRESS
                button.text = str(row * 4 + col)
                button.pressed.connect(_on_button_pressed)
                if col == 1:
                    button.set_pressed_no_signal(true)


func _on_button_pressed():
    print("Button " + button.text + " was pressed.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I needed to use a lambda function. Final code was:

```
button.pressed.connect(func():_on_button_pressed(button))
```

```
func _on_button_pressed(button):
    print("Button " + button.text + " was pressed.")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with the _on_button_pressed function.
"button" does not exists in the function's context
You need to add a parameter to the _on_button_pressed function that will receive the button object that was pressed